# Python Websockets receive Raw Bytes

Tags: python, websocket, encoding, character-encoding, byte

I've been using the python `websockets` library of 8.1 version. This has been a good tool for receiving string data, yet now I have experienced a need to receive a mixture of string and bytes data.

Let me explain.

There is a socket, which encodes its data with the algorithm, which uses character codes as numbers.

For example, at the beginning of the message it has a character `c`, whose `ord(c) == 777`. It doesn't mean, though, that this is a `chr(777)`, as a human would read it. It represents, for example, the type of message the client got. So it's a message with the type `777`, and there is an algorithm to handle this type of messages. The next character would represent the lenght of the message. And so on.

There is a problem, though. There is a message, whose type is `0`, which means a `NUL` byte. When the client receives such a string, for some reason either `Python` or the `websockets` `recv` method interpretes it as a `space` character, resulting in `ord(c) == 32` instead of `ord(c) == 0`. Which, obviously, makes the whole message incorrect. I could replace 32 with 0 and vice versa, yet it would lead to even more errors, as those characters are not interchangable.

I suppose, if I received `bytes` instead of `str`, the problem would go away? But I cannot seem to find a method for that. Maybe, someone had such experience in the past with `python` and/or `websockets` incorrectly treating unreadable characters?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the struct module to build your packets
https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html